# How to compress URL parameters as Google Map by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, url, compression

How to compress URL parameters as `data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x808fcae48af93ff5:0xb99d8c0aca9f717b`

https://www.google.com/maps/place/San+Jose,+CA/@37.2970156,-121.8174129,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x808fcae48af93ff5:0xb99d8c0aca9f717b

I tried atob and btoa, crypto-js but the result URL is too long.
[How to encrypt/decrypt URL parameters in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819407/how-to-encrypt-decrypt-url-parameters-in-javascript)
https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/