# How to achieve state persistance on tab reload?

Tags: javascript, angular, web

### Simplified Use case

I have a working single page web app called ***data_store***. This app has 2 simple tasks list

1. List users
2. Show user details (when a user is clicked).

Now for this, I have 2 ***routes***

1. data_store/all_user
2. data_store/user_detail

*For the sake of simplicity, all other factors can be ignored.

---

> **Problem:** When I reload the tab my at `data_store/user_detail`, I loose on the ***unique ID*** of the user whose details were to be shown.

> **Question:** How can I persist the ***unique ID*** on tab reload? and make it work seamlessly across duplicated tabs?

---

### Failed Solutions

1st, use `data_store/user_detail/<UUID>` format but I cannot expose it in my URL for security reasons.

2nd, use `local_storage` to store current UUID, but then the reload of other tabs with different user's details breaks.
Reason: as they pick up the last set value by any other tab also.

3rd, use `session_storage` but the problem is that while duplicating tabs instead of opening a new one. The chrome to duplicate a tab uses the window.open and generates a daughter tab that shares all the info from its parent, including sessionStorage.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can put the user's crypted identifier in the URL, If you encryption is based on a seed then it should be possible to encrypt/decrypt it, and make it unavailable for some basic hacker.

I have found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19822677/9868549) refering to a low level of encryption, maybe it can help you.

For a Higher encryption level, [crypto-js](https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/) could be a solution.

Now, if you don't want parameters in your url and don't need to support IE < edge 14, maybe you can try to [get the tab id](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/get) and store your data with it, so on reload it will be easy to associate data with tabs. I don't know its behavior with tab duplication tho.