# Ionic 5 React page crashes on device when window location href has email

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework

I have a ionic-refresher component, and in it i am trying to use window.location.href, and it works when i do not have any variables in the value, like this

```
window.location.href = '/tab1';
```

but it does not work when i do have variables, like this

```
window.location.href = '/listing/' + id
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

What i have tried is `window.open()`, `window.replace()`, `history.go(0)`, `history.push()`.

Full code here

```
<IonRefresher slot='fixed' onIonRefresh={doRefresh} 
    pullFactor={0.5} pullMin={100} pullMax={200}>
    <IonRefresherContent></IonRefresherContent>
</IonRefresher>

function doRefresh(event: CustomEvent<RefresherEventDetail>) {
        
        // window.open("/listings/" + id.id, "_self")
        
        // history.push("/listings/" + id.id)
  
        // history.go(0)

      }
```

EDIT: It's able to catch the variables, but not email id specifically. I will make it work with user id instead of email id.

Comment: maybe concatenate the string and the variable first, store it as a new variable (or even the old one) and set the href equal to only your new var?

Comment: @baby_boy tried it, doesn't work

Comment: don't know then, I just thought the program your using might not like two values

Answer (score 0):

First Upon you will check that you define your path with id like `<Route path="/listings/:id" component={listening}/>` in App.js

then you will do

```
function doRefresh(event: CustomEvent<RefresherEventDetail>) {
      
     history.push(`/listings/${id.id}`)
        
  }
```

Comment: I already have a route with ```<Route path='/listing/:id component={listings} />``` but it is still not able to get that. I made an edit to the question. It works with a string without email id.

Comment: have you get an id with in the function?

Comment: Yes i have a different Id i can work with, which does not have email address in it.

Comment: email_id, you mean?

Comment: here you go https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kgqbjq
yes email id

Comment: i think it contains a type annotation that can only be supported by typescript and stackblitz is react only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227931/discussion-between-rijo-rajan-and-sid0972).

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who is wondering, i encoded the url using base64 and then decoded it to handle email address. More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819407/how-to-encrypt-decrypt-url-parameters-in-javascript)